# How to match data and combine two arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My database gives me the following data:

```js
var responses = [
          { comment: 'Yes', uid: '5hg' },
          { comment: 'Maybe', uid: 'f1' },
          { comment: 'No', uid: 'b1k2' },
          { comment: 'Yes', uid: '6t2' },
          { comment: 'Yes', uid: 'hd1' },
        ];

var users = [
          { name: 'Trevor Hansen', group: 'Group 1', uid: 'f1' },
          { name: 'Britta Holt', group: 'Group 2', uid: '5hg' },
          { name: 'Jane Smith ', group: 'Group 2', uid: '6t2' },
          { name: 'Sandra Adams', group: 'Group 1', uid: 'c92c' },
          { name: 'Ali Connors', group: 'Group 1', uid: 'b2' },
          { name: 'John Smith', group: 'Group 2', uid: '9l2' },
          { name: 'Sandra Williams', group: 'Group 2', uid: 'hd1' },
          { name: 'Tucker Smith', group: 'Group 1', uid: 'b1k2' },
        ];
```

Because I store all of my user data only in `users[]` for different purposes I need to add some information to `responses[]` about the user (like their `name` and `group`). The `uid` is unique and can be used to match the data to a user.

Obviously there are less responses than users in `responses[]`. This should not affect my function and is an expected behavior.

This is the desired output:

```js
var output = [
          { comment: 'Yes', uid: '5hg', name: 'Britta Holt', group: 'Group 2' },
          { comment: 'Maybe', uid: 'f1', name: 'Trevor Hansen', group: 'Group 1' },
          { comment: 'No', uid: 'b1k2', name: 'Tucker Smith', group: 'Group 1' },
          { comment: 'Yes', uid: '6t2', name: 'Jane Smith ', group: 'Group 2' },
          { comment: 'Yes', uid: 'hd1', name: 'Sandra Williams', group: 'Group 2' },
        ];
```

How can this be done? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks, that's a good one. Didn't came across this question and will take  a look at it.

Comment: @mcd hint? Doesn't answer the question you have? It joins two arrays based on a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try for example:

```
const output = responses.map(response => {
  const user = users.find(u => u.uid === response.uid);
  return {...response, ...user}
})
```

or single liner:

```
const output = responses.map(response => ({...response, ...users.find(u => u.uid === response.uid)}));
```

Comment: or single liner: var output = responses.map(response => ({...response, ...users.find(u => u.uid === response.uid)}))